# Javascript regex to replace "split"

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to use **Javascript Regex** instead of `split`.

Here is the example string:

```
var str = "123:foo";
```

The current method calls:

```
str.split(":")[1]
```

This will return `"foo"`, but it raises an Error when given a bad string that doesn't have a `:`.

So this would raise an error:

```
var str = "fooblah";
```

In the case of `"fooblah"` I'd like to just return an **empty string**.

This should be pretty simple, but went looking for it, and couldn't figure it out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could just split the string, then check the length of the array to make sure you won't get an error.

Comment: `str.split(":")[1] || ""`

Comment: I'd prefer to see @Andreas line of code.

Comment: *This will return "foo", but it raises an Error when given a bad string that doesn't have a `:`.* No, it doesn't. It merely returns undefined. So in that case just do `str.split(":")[1] || ''`--what's the problem?

Comment: Will your string have multiple colons?

Comment: @torazaburo no it won't only the possibility of one `:` or none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex won't help you. Your error likely arises from trying to use `undefined` later. Instead, check the length of the split first.

```
var arr = str.split(':');
if (arr.length < 2) {
  // Do something to handle a bad string
} else {
  var match = arr[1];
  ...
}
```

Comment: Or if you like one-liners: `var match = str.split(':')[1] || '';`

Answer (score 3):

Remove the part up to and including the colon (or the end of the string, if there's no colon):

```
"123:foo".replace(/.*?(:|$)/, '')    // "foo"
"foobar" .replace(/.*?(:|$)/, '')    // ""
```

How this regexp works:

```
.*                 Grab everything
?                  non-greedily
(                  until we come to
  :                a colon
  |                or 
  $                the end of the string
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I've always used, with different variations; this is just a simple version of it:

```
function split(str, d) {
    var op = "";
    if(str.indexOf(d) > 0) {
        op = str.split(d);
    }
    return(op);
}
```

Fairly simple, either returns an array or an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str1 = "123:foo", str2 = "fooblah";

var res = function (s) {
  return /:/.test(s) && s.replace(/.*(?=:):/, "") || ""
};

console.log(res(str1), res(str2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a single regex, with the part you want in the capturing group:

```
^[^:]*:([^:]+)
```

Comment: Note he wants the part after the colon.

Comment: I'm failing to see why this could not simply be `/:(.*)/`.

Comment: @torazaburo - That's probably fine, I was attempting to make mine a little more robust, so that if there are possibly more colons, it only matches the second non-colon string.